# User block in data base

Tags: sql, concurrency, block

I would like to know more about the internal behavior of a sql_server.

My problem is that I'm trying to create a multi-user data base but I'm experimenting concurrency data problems.

As an example:

1. UserA opens an application and modifies something in the tableA without committing.
2. UserB opens also the application and tries to read the tableA too.
3. UserB is blocked until userA commits

My questions are:

1. How can I resolve that?
2. Isn't there a way for giving the userB old information, letting him know that the information is old?

Comment: With "sql_server" you mean *Microsoft* SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> opens an aplication an modify something in the tableA without
>   comitting

Don't write applications that do this. No application should hold locks for the duration of *user* actions. Editing a form should not lock the data. Read about [Optimistic Concurency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa0416cz.aspx).

Application will still block occasionaly and the best approach is to deploy row based versioning, aka. SNAPSHOT ISOLATION. See [Understanding Row Versioning-Based Isolation Levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189050%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx).

Comment: I know that it is bad that why I wanna modify it :)
Let me know if I have understood it. I have to chage the isolation level of my data base in order to it allows me to read something also if it wasn't committed. Making that I will have dirty reads. Threfore, I will need to develope Optimistic concurrency methods for resolve those dirty reads. 
is it right?

Comment: Read the links in the answer for solutions.

Answer (score 0):

> *UserB is blocked until userA commits*

That is not true for any modern DBMS. Nearly all of them implement some kind of [MVCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) so that writers do block readers and readers do not block writers.

If I'm not mistaken this is still the default behaviour for Microsoft SQL Server (even in 2012) but can be changed to allow for higher concurrency

Comment: Thank you very much. That was the information that I was looking for :)